# Publish Bot - Composer - Import from Existing Resources

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, publish

I had few permission related issues due to my account being a one from organization. So decided to make use of "Import using existing resources". Please find the .json below that was used to create the publishing profile.

{
"name": "convAISubAuto",
"environment": "dev",
"tenantId": "TENANT_ID",
"hostname": "subAutoConvAI", #Same as azure bot name
"runtimeIdentifier": "win-x64",
"resourceGroup": "chatbot",
"botName": "subAutoConvAI", #Same as azure bot name
"subscriptionId": "SUB_ID",
"region": "westus",
"appServiceOperatingSystem": "windows",
"scmHostDomain": "",
"luisResource": "convAIBoth",
"settings": {
"applicationInsights": {
"InstrumentationKey": "",
"connectionString": ""
},
"cosmosDb": {
"cosmosDBEndpoint": "",
"authKey": "",
"databaseId": "botstate-db",
"containerId": "botstate-container"
},
"blobStorage": {
"connectionString": "",
"container": ""
},
"luis": {
"authoringKey": "",
"authoringEndpoint": "",
"endpointKey": "",
"endpoint": "",
"region": "eastus"
},
"qna": {
"subscriptionKey": "",
"endpoint": ""
},
"MicrosoftAppId": "APP_ID", #Taken from Azure bot configurations screen
"MicrosoftAppPassword": "***" #Taken from secret generated during app registration
}
}

The bot is getting published successfully. However, when i click on "Test in Web Chat" option inside the Azure Bot Resource, i am getting blank screen.

Also, inside the configuration for Azure bot... The endpoint mentioned was https://host_name/api/messages. I had to mention it as the field was blank.

Is there any issue with my publishing profile's JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is as follows.

1. Do a app registration and generate a secret.
2. Create an Azure bot and during the first step, there's an option for "Use existing app registration", inside it mention the app ID and secret (app password)
3. Use the same app ID and app Password on the above json file.

This solved the issue.